# Yii's accessRules misconception

Tags: php, access-control, yii

I'm trying to build a site using Yii, and found myself in a situation which requires some clarifications on access control metaphor in Yii. Specifically, one can override [accessRules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#accessRules-detail) method in `CController`'s descendant.

**Prerequisite:**

Here is a code generated by default by Gii, much similar to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth):

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'roles'=> array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

**The Question:**

What is not clear here to me, is -- *why we need to define access rules for many different users and groups, and different actions instead of checking rights of only one current user and action?* -- here in italics my main question is highlighted, just in case it may not so clear for readers (answer authors).

This code is executed in a context of specific request, for which **a specific `controller`, a specific `action`, and a specific `user` are already known**. If, for example, the user is a guest, I don't see any reason to define rules for "admin" role or authenticated users.

**Reasoning:**

After some elaboration I came up to the following implementation:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
      array(Yii::app()->user->hasRights()?'allow':'deny'),
      );
}
```

where `hasRights` is a simple custom method added into a `CWebUser` descendant:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
  private $ACL = // ACL example
    array('user' => // controller id
      array('index' => User::AC_MODERATOR, // action ids
            'view' => User::AC_MODERATOR,
            'create' => User::AC_MODERATOR,
            'update' => User::AC_ADMIN,
            'delete' => User::AC_ADMIN,
            'admin' => User::AC_ADMIN),
           // ...
      );

  public function hasRights()
  {
    return (Yii::app()->user->getState('accessRights') >=
      $this->ACL[Yii::app()->controller->id][Yii::app()->controller->action->id]);
  }
}
```

As you may see, `hasRights` uses current user "rights" (read from DB as usual), current controller and action to calculate single boolean `true` or `false` value as a decision about access.

What is wrong with this approach? Why Yii does not use something simple like that by default?

The Gii-generated `accessRules` above do not only look excessive, but also imply that access rules are scattered among many controllers. In my approach a single and compact ACL is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's where I think you're confused.

First of all, Yii is in fact only looking at the current user and the current action.  Just like how you got the current permissions for the controller by grabbing a nested array, indexed by the controller ID, Yii is creating an instance of your controller and only looking at those access rules.  Also, just like you're only looking at the permissions of a particular action, Yii is only looking at the rules pertaining to the current action.  It accesses those permissions just as easily as you return the value of the nested array.

As far as the user goes, it's also only looking at the current user; the current user name, the current user role, etc.  The difference is, there are multiple attributes Yii will allow within a rule, in contrast to the single permission value associated with the user.

It seems what you don't like about this approach is you think permissions should be handled all in one place.  This could be simpler in some cases, but more difficult in others.  What happens when you have multiple controllers and multiple actions in each controller?  You now have a very large array to manage, that references data from multiple different contexts.  In the way Yii does it, the current controller has control over how it's data structure can be accessed.  This lines up with Yii's MVC structure, and the concept of encapsulation.

Your solution is more elegant in some respects, but it hinges on the idea that permissions will only ever need to be structured in a cascading one directional structure.  What I mean is your permissions are like one long hallway, with doors separating one area from another.  If the user doesn't have the key to one door, they shouldn't be able to access the next, etc.  But what happens if, in your example, you need a user to both view content, and update it without being able to create new content?  This is a much more complicated scenario which will need to be handled using roles.  So then you'd have to process rules within your array, much like Yii does.  Except instead of Yii's object oriented approach, you've got everything embedded in one long array.

So perhaps your solution will work in some cases, but I'm sure you can see why Yii chose its approach since it will work, by default, for far more situations.

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting your answer cause it seems rational. Yes, Yii _works_ the same way as you described but _uses_ too wordy code for this, which I don't like. My approach is not less OO, then Yii's - the only difference is in refactoring with `WebUser` object obtaining part of ACL service functions from `Controller`. Both Yii's and my code use arrays under the hood. As for the "_hallway_" concept, it can be easily extended to random access table just by using bitwise operations. I just don't need it at the moment. Yet I admit Yii's approach more flexible.

Comment: Good point about bitwise operations.  One caveat, though, is things could become complicated if you have a controller that interacts with more than one model.  What if you have more than one 'create' action, or you have an action that creates two models; or what if you need someone to have permission to create a model, but need to restrict a certain property on that model.  Just something to consider.  Have you looked into Yii's rights extensions?  I've used this one with some success: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/

Answer (score 0):

Yii implements a hierarchical RBAC scheme via its CWebApplication ->authManager application component, which actually similar to what you did,

Take a look at [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme/)

**EDIT**

```
"let us suppose that we use RBAC and add some rules into the accessRules method, such as with admin role in the example above."
```

you don't add rules into accessRules method when you use RBAC

what you do is , you define authorization hierarchy which involves three steps
1)define authorization itmes which includes roles and operations, 
this would be stored in DB,in authitem table

Eg.
**Operations**

```
siteAddProduct->in this case 'site' is the controller name and addProduct is the action in 'site' controller
sitedeleteProduct ...etc
```

**Roles**

```
admin,editor...etc
```

2)Estabish relationship between authorization items(between role and operations) this would be stored in authitemchild table

eg.

```
admin -> siteAddProduct
editor -> sitedeleteProduct
admin->editor
```

3)assign roles to application users this would be stored in authassignment table

for example
**userid 1 ->admin**

now in your base controller( assuming that you have a controller class from which all other controllers in your app extneds from )
you override `beforeAction()` method and check the logged in user(current user) permission using

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($operation);
```

$operation is the requested controller + action

you can get the controller name using `$this->id` and action name using
 `$this->getAction()->id`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know this. RBAC requires to run additional procedure to configure roles and assign them to users which seems strange, because corresponding data is already available in domain models. I do not need such duplication. Anyway, let us suppose that we use RBAC and add some rules into the `accessRules` method, such as with admin role in the example above. The question remains the same: why do we need to define rules for other actions and users than current action and user?

Comment: I know what is RBAC. I just noted that we use roles defined in RBAC in the `accessRules` method, thus adding access rules involving roles. The answer does not still answer the question.

Comment: why would you use accessRules method if you already implemented RBAC

Comment: My question is about `accessRules` default implementation, not about RBAC.